# Does the chance of a treasure chest change per level?

Tags: clicker-heroes

Is there any difference between the levels in view of the treasure chest spawn chance?

I know that there is a relic which will raise the chance of a treasure chest by 20% per level. But I have some levels where the treasure chest nearly appears all 5-10 enemies and I have some levels which seem to spawn no treasure chest. Watched it for quite 5 minutes which killed nearly 300 enemies, but no treasure chest at all.

If there is a difference, how can I determine it?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a set random chance (independent of the level), which can be modified by ancients and relics. But I have no concrete evidence of that.

Comment: Looking at the code, the chance is `CHANCE_OF_TREASURE_MONSTER * (1 + this.ancients.treasureChestSpawnPercent * 0.01);`. `CHANCE_OF_TREASURE_MONSTER ` is a constant that is exactly 0.01 (1%). It appears to me that the RNG (random number generator) is more biased to larger numbers though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any difference between the treasure chest spawn rate depending on what level you're on.  It's a base 1% whether you're on level 100 or 1000%.  [Source](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Chest)

A maxed [Dora](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Dora,_Ancient_of_Discovery) will give you a +1000% percent chance of a treasure chest spawn; which works out to roughly 1 out of every 9 (or 11%).

Relics would also give you a boosted chance to get a treasure chest spawn; but I highly doubt it's per level.  If it was; I'd think that eventually you'd hit a point where every monster is a treasure chest; and that would probably break game balance.

Comment: It's definitely not 'per level' [of the game world] (unless you mean per level of Dora).